# Defining methods in Java

Tags: java

I just got an assignment back, which was marked down due to the following method definition:

```
static String[] getDayData (int day) {
```

I was told:

> Your functions should *always* have the definer `public`/`private`/`protected` in them.

Despite the fact that I disagree with the function part in Java, It clearly states [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) that:

> The only required elements of a method declaration are the method's return type, name, a pair of parentheses, `()`, and a body between braces, `{}`.

So who has any thoughts on this? Should I always include a modifier in the method's definition or not?

Comment: It's personal preference. It defaults to protected in Java, so it's not explicitly required.

Comment: defaults to protected? are you sure?

Comment: It is considered good practice since it avoids confusion, as in Bela Vizer's comment. If you don't know for sure what it defaults to, how can you know you just did the right thing?

Comment: r.e. "It defaults to protected" => not true, defaults to "default" which is protected + access from same package. Extremely bad practice IMO as does not hide implementation details a strongly as protected/private.

Comment: The word "always" being included in what you were told *almost* always means it isn't right...

Comment: I'm weary of any statements that employ words like "always" or "never".  It usually (not always!) means that the person making the statement doesn't really know what they are talking about.

Comment: Considering explicit is better than implicit, it is better to be include the modifier in the method definition. However, you can leave it in case it is obvious to everyone.

Comment: Personally I would have marked you down for using arrays and static, and let the default access pass :)

Comment: @Adam you've got it backwards - `protected` is "default" + subclasses.

Comment: No modifier means package access or "package-private" as explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That statement, taken at face value, is definitely wrong. If what you wanted to declare is a package-private method, then **this is the only way to do it**. That declaration cannot possibly be added an access modifier without having its meaning changed.

What exactly your teacher has in mind with his marking criteria is a separate issue, but from my own teaching experience I cannot agree with that comment. Teaching Java 101 absolutely does include **all method access levels**.

On a side note, I can also not agree with his arbitrary use of "function" instead of the official term "method". This is just bad teaching in my book, and whether the underlying cause is ignorance of Java or just misguided didactics is not to be discerned from the information we have. And... did he really use the term "definer"? This term doesn't even exist—whether in Java or elsewhere.

Comment: +1 The teacher is incorrect. See the table [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) as well.

Comment: +1 the "teacher" is a moron.

Comment: Let's just not judge that teacher too quickly. The detail may be left out of his recommendation if it's a beginner level course. The word "always" is poorly chosen, but maybe the teacher just intended to make a recommendation which I think is justified.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester In real-world practice the package-private access level is indispensable.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - I happen to agree with you. Most of these comments come from 'seasoned' pros who might actually have use for package level access. But most students omit the access level due to carelessness, not design. Some of these pros need to spend time in a classroom.

Comment: That might all be true, but he shouldn't mark down the assignment for the reason of *always* requiring a visibility

Comment: @Perception I spent my share of time in the classroom and even wrote the whole class curriculum from scratch. One thing I can tell you for sure is that I'd be very careful with my terminology: in Java there's no functions; there's **methods**.

Answer (score 2):

When programming in a team, not everyone will always be familiar with the language you are employing. The Java language specification does not **require** an access modifier for class members, but if you state it explicitly, it will be clear to everyone what you intend to do. The only exception of course, is the case Marko Topolnik mentioned, where you need a package private method. Although, I believe there are few common design patterns that make use of those. I can't even think of a logical situation where you'd need them.

Answer (score 2):

There are four visibility levels for Java fields and methods, each "wider" than the last:

1. `private` - visible only within this class
2. "default" (i.e. no modifier) - visible to this class and other classes in the same package
3. `protected` - visible to this class, other classes in the same package, and also subclasses of this class that are in other packages
4. `public` - visible everywhere

so it is valid to have a method with no modifier.  Some coding styles I've seen make package visibility more explicit with a comment like

```
/* package-private */ static int foo() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

While this might be considered a style question and you could be graded on that basis, methods and classes using default visibility can be valuable. The default visibility in Java is package level visibility see this [part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of the Java tutorial. I tend to use it when writing libraries. There are functions, and some fields, which I want to access from within other classes in my library, but are intended solely for internal use. When writing in other languages, such as php, I find myself missing this level of visibility and instead resorting to comments with functions declared public saying they are "Internal Only". With this default level it's important to note that subpackages are considered different packages and won't be able to see functions with this visibility level.

It's unlikely to get you points back as you probably intended it for use outside of the package.